# The perplexity of 'offshore' and 'outsource'

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage

We are an IT company in India that **receives** IT projects from the first world countries. I search for the terms *offshore/offshoring', 'outsource/outsourcing', and leads me to confusion.

Who are we?

> (a) An outsource company? 
>  (b) An outsourcing company? 
>  (c) An offshore company? 
>  (d) An offshoring company?

If we are 'outsourcing company'; do ***we*** outsource? No, we don't! 
Do **we** offshore something? No, we don't!

Furthermore, *Offshoring* is a noun ([Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/offshoring?showCookiePolicy=true) and [OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/offshoring)) and not an adjective! But then **[offshoring company](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=offshoring%20company&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_P6PVJnROtG2uASy94GADA#tbm=nws&q=%22offshoring%20company%22)** is a  widely used phrase.

For a verb usage, OALD suggests '[*offshore something*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/offshoring)' but then what if I want to use a present continuous for that as we do with other words? *Offshoring something* then becomes noun!

Comment: Related (and perhaps helpful to anyone wanting to answer): [Difference between offshoring and outsourcing](http://diversifyiss.com/content/so-what-are-benefits-offshoring). If you don't offshore and you don't outsource, perhaps you could settle for calling yourselves an _international company_. (From [MoneyGlossary.com](http://www.moneyglossary.com/?w=International) –
**International** *Definition*: Anything having to do with more than one country.)

Comment: About the use of a noun as an attributive, _offshoring company_ is no stranger than an _oil company_ or a _pet store_. Nouns are often used in this way and the fact that offshoring is a noun does not make it a strange construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whoever is sending you the projects will refer to your firm as an *offshore company*, because you are located in a different country, and almost certainly *overseas* (the reason that the term *offshore* arose in this context). Your company doesn't offshore something; rather, you and your deliverables *are* the offshore something. Companies hired to produce work by other, extranational firms may not refer to themselves as "offshore", instead preferring something a little more upscale sounding, as some people would draw negative inferences from the term, though it doesn't imply anything of the sort on its own.

*Offshoring company* is not a term used in American English; neither is it used in British English in my experience, though I don't have as much in technical work in BrE as in AmE. This seems to be an Indian English construction, because every hit in your linked search is about Indian companies. And not very many at that; I see only three pages of results, and most items are about the same few stories. Compare with ["offshore company"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=offshoring%20company&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=_P6PVJnROtG2uASy94GADA#tbm=nws&q=%22offshore%20company%22) and you can see this is the preferred term. Both are used to convey the same meaning.

You are not an *outsourcing company*. Such a company provides the service of finding external employees or shops for other companies to ship their work to, or, sometimes, performs the work themselves. *Outsource company* has the same meaning (but seems to be more likely to refer to companies who do the work, as opposed to finding workers). Note that such companies, whether they do the work or find workers, need not be located outside the hiring firm's nation, while *offshore companies* are.

Why is *offshore* preferred over *offshoring* but *outsourcing* preferred over *outsource*? Because English. More helpfully (but perhaps a bit less accurately), because an *offshore company* is an extranationally located company - *offshore* references the location, thus it's an adjective - while an *outsourcing company* performs *outsourcing* services - *outsourcing* references the activity the company does, thus it's a gerund.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 but if I refer my company as an 'Offshore company', is that okay?

Comment: Certainly it's OK, and is especially appropriate if completing offshored work is your company's primary business. If that isn't the case and such work is a minor or incidental aspect of your business, you might want to avoid using that term when the offshore aspect isn't relevant, lest it confuse people. Perhaps something along the lines of *consulting* or *production* would be appropriate in that case, to convey that your company is hired to do work for others.

Answer (score 0):

J.R.'s [comment above](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43175/the-perplexity-of-offshore-and-outsource#comment80309_43175) gave some good links about the difference between these two words, as well as their definitions.

In short, "to outsource" means essentially to hire some remote company to do some aspect of your work for you. For example, if I didn't want to handle my customer support calls, I could route them to a company in another country with whom I have a contract to handle them.

"To offshore" generally involves a more direct relationship, wherein the company works closely with, if not directly employs, the remote workers.

When you get into "offshoring" and "outsourcing" companies, that becomes a term-of-art. I'm not knowledgeable enough about the technical English language to tell you much more on that front, but essentially a bunch of people in the field have just decided over the years that an "offshoring company" should mean a company that handles offshored work.

I definitely agree with you on the technicality, that "offshoring company" *should* be synonymous with "company that offshores," but it just isn't really, at least in practical usage. Although honestly, I could even respect you being called a company that outsources.

The difficulty comes here in that there's a *relationship* being described. A single company can't outsource something on their own, they need someone to outsource it *to*. So in typical usage, that relationship isn't generally brought up, but if I were to expand out "company that offshores" to its implied form, I'd probably say "company that offshores work **{to | from}** another company."

As such, you are a company that outsources from other companies, and Microsoft is a company that outsources to other companies.

It's just a matter of context and usage.

As for "an offshore company," I probably wouldn't call myself that if I were you. You aren't offshore to yourself (by definition). I might, as a person in the United States, describe you as an offshore company, just as you might describe Stack Exchange as one to you. That's just relative to position. Anyone will know what you mean, it just sounds a little awkward to me personally to hear what essentially amounts to "I'm on the other side of the ocean!"

Comment: "company that offshores work {to | from} another company." I'd say *offshores to*, since *offshore* means *send work overseas to be produced or completed by a different company*; *from* would make little sense.